# Python Pandas If value in column D equals Windows Print Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that looks like this
"IP","DNS","NetBIOS","OS"
"x.x.x","name","name","Windows 2012"
"x.x.x","name","name","HP JetDirect"

I am trying to find a way using Pandas to have the code look in the OS column, if it equals "Windows" (anything after the "Windows" does not matter), it will print the word "Workstation" if it is anything else it will print "Printer"

I also have this line of code that would insert the new column. But I would need it to know what value to print based on the question above

```
df.insert(4,'Report Category',' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'))
0     True
1    False
Name: OS, dtype: bool

#for last column
df['Report Category'] = np.where(df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'), 'Workstation', 'Printer')
print (df)
      IP   DNS NetBIOS            OS Report Category
0  x.x.x  name    name  Windows 2012     Workstation
1  x.x.x  name    name  HP JetDirect         Printer
```

And for `4th`column use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(4,'Report Category', np.where(df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'),
                                       'Workstation', 'Printer'))
print (df)
      IP   DNS NetBIOS            OS Report Category
0  x.x.x  name    name  Windows 2012     Workstation
1  x.x.x  name    name  HP JetDirect         Printer
```

Comment: Does this still add the Report Category column in the 4th column?

Comment: What is the purpose of the following? 
"print (df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'))
0     True
1    False
Name: OS, dtype: bool". 
Does this need to be printed out like you have?
Also, can I have more than the 0,1 True/False in this? Could it account for 3,4,5 more options?

Comment: I try answer for your questions - 1. It is only mask which is use in solution - if value is `True`, add first string, if False another. In real solution `print (df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'))` can be omit.2. Yes, sure, there works very nice with 1000s rows of data.

Comment: 3. yes, sure, it is possible also. Need nested `numpy.where` - `df = pd.DataFrame({'IP': {0: 'x.x.x', 1: 'x.x.x', 2: 'x.x.x', 3: 'x.x.x', 4: 'x.x.x', 5: 'x.x.x'}, 'OS': {0: 'Windows 2012', 1: 'Linux BSC', 2: 'macOS 01', 3: 'macOS 01', 4: 'Windows 2012', 5: 'HP JetDirect'}, 'NetBIOS': {0: 'name', 1: 'name', 2: 'name', 3: 'name', 4: 'name', 5: 'name'}, 'DNS': {0: 'name', 1: 'name', 2: 'name', 3: 'name', 4: 'name', 5: 'name'}}).reindex_axis(['DNS', 'IP', 'NetBIOS', 'OS'], axis=1)
print (df)`

Comment: and `df['Report Category'] = np.where(df['OS'].str.contains('Windows'), 'Workstation',
                        np.where(df['OS'].str.contains('Linux'), 'Linux',
                        np.where(df['OS'].str.contains('macOS'), 'MaC',
                                 'Printer')))` - simply for each condition one where and last number of parentheses by count of where

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the explanation as well I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day. and thank you for accepting!